# Converting a Zip Code to Zip Code + 4 MySQL

Tags: mysql

Are you able to convert a Zip Code to a Z+4 in MySQL? I'm running into an issue where I have some Zip Codes that have a variety of digits.

For example, we ship to Puerto Rico and their Zip Codes start with two zeroes: 00XXX

This would give me text of just the three numbers "XXX" without the leading zeroes.

For states such as Maine, Zip Codes start with one zero: 0XXXX

This would give me just the four numbers "XXXX".

For most of the states in the United States, I would get a standard five char zip code which is fine. However, what if a customer also typed in their Z+4? I would have 9 characters.

What makes it even more complicated are when customers in the northeast US give a Z+4. (0XXXX-XXXX)

So I would regularly have the following types for my Zip Code field.

Puerto Rico (XXX); 
Northeast US (XXXX); 
Regular Zip (XXXXX); 
Northeast US + 4 (XXXXXXXX); 
Regular Zip + 4 (XXXXXXXXX)

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can convert them. I know what data type it should be. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Also, what if I wanted the "-" in the Zip Code + 4? Such that it would be XXXXX-XXXX or 0XXXX-XXXX?

Currently I'm using varchar(10) but when I import it, the leading zero is taken off from my text file anyway. In that case, I have to convert the Zip already to that format of XXXXX-XXXX or 0XXXX-XXXX then upload it. Just wanted to make this automated and not have to worry about missing a Zip and having an error in shipment.

Comment: Is this a one time thing or are you wanting to do this on insert/update?

Comment: You should use a `Char(9)` or `VARCHAR(9)`. Zip codes are not numbers, and using a data type that is will remove the leading zero (`0`) as you've indicated. Since a valid zip code for Maine is 5 characters starting with `"0"`, a numeric type will never allow you to store it; a character type column will keep the leading `"0"`.

Comment: We get orders constantly, few thousand a day. I've been converting them currently via an excel formula I worked out, but I have a problem with 8 character Zips (Like the Northeast US + 4) in excel. I wanted a more automated way to avoid any mistakes.

Comment: Something like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17803/12

Comment: Zip codes should be stored as a `varchar(6)` to accommodate US, MX and CA postal codes. The Zip+4 part should be stored separately in a `varchar(4)` field.

Comment: @gvee, very close. However, I normally am not able to import it with the leading zero. I can play around with what you gave me, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for US Postal Codes.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN `PostalCode` < 999 THEN CONCAT('00', `PostalCode`, '-0000')
WHEN `PostalCode` < 9999 THEN CONCAT('0', `PostalCode`, '-0000')
WHEN `PostalCode` < 99999 THEN CONCAT(`PostalCode`, '-0000')
WHEN `PostalCode` < 99999999 THEN CONCAT('0',LEFT(`PostalCode`, 4),'-',RIGHT(`PostalCode`, 4)) 
ELSE CONCAT(LEFT(`PostalCode`,5),'-',RIGHT(`PostalCode`, 4)) END as PostalCodeConversion
FROM YourTable;
```

Hope this can help anyone that needed an answer.